# jquery's version of ".innerHTML +=" for an array html insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have read through some questions pertaining specifically to innerHTML= vs .html().  But yet have crossed anything to add into the variable like innerHTML+= to the html().  Is there a jquery event that can add more than just one html string?  Or shall I rely on innerHTML+= for now?

The coding that best describes the current issue:

```
var pushy = ['blah', 'blaH', 'blaah'];

for(i=0;i<pushy.length;i++){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += 
"<div>Im one heck of a div and more!</div>" + pushy[i];}
```

vs

```
$("#demo").html("<div>Im one heck of a div and more!</div>" + pushy[i]);
//where it will return the last array value and not the first value
```

Although the first is the go to and failsafe.  But wanted to see the exact equivalent than just pop the last value of the array.  Here is my [innerHTML+= vs .html()](https://jsfiddle.net/NitroXAce/4pqegj5f/7/) for example.  The question is not pertaining to the innerHTML `=` but rather the `+=` thereof.

Comment: have you tried `.append`?

Comment: there is a jquery function .appened available for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `.append()`

`$('element').append('SOME HTML');`

You example (updated)
https://jsfiddle.net/4pqegj5f/9/

Comment: That would be the one! Thank you my kind sir!

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for

`$("#demo").append("<div>Im one heck of a div and more!</div>" + pushy[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

Using .append should get you the desired result. See below:

```js
var pushy = ['blah', 'blaH', 'blaah'];

for(i=0;i<pushy.length;i++){
$("#demo").append("<div>Im one heck of a div and more!</div>" + pushy[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```